# How to find out parallel dependencies

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-libraries

I recently learned that the counter in a **std::shared_ptr** has to be atomic in order to be thread safe, which is a big argument against using it. Other example of parallel dependencies are the memory allocation.

Is there a reliable way to detect what are the parallel dependencies in a compiled program, i.e. to identify the potential possibility of parallel contention?

To be more precise, if a **std::shared_ptr** is used in a serial context with no possibility of sharing, then I think the compiler would remove the atomics, but how to be sure?

Comment: Who told you that the reference counter being atomic "is a big argument against using it"? Whoever told you that was 100% wrong. As far as compiler optimization goes, it is highly unlikely that a compiler will have any idea whether or not the application has any running threads, and, as such, it is safe to optimize-away the entire reference-counting 2nd pointer that `std::shared_ptr` constructs, internally.

Comment: One reference is for example [link](http://seanmiddleditch.com/dangers-of-stdshared_ptr/)

Comment: The linked article points out some problems with `std::shared_ptr`, and I actually agree with many of the points stated. I also happen to agree that `std::shared_ptr` is broken in several ways. But its problems have nothing to do with atomics. The cited article only mentions it in passing, and I don't know where you got the idea that the biggest problem with `std::shared_ptr` is the overhead of an atomic reference counter. The linked article doesn't even attempt to obtain any kind of a metric as to what the overhead is. The overhead is negligible. You'll be hard-pressed to actually see it.